# Visual C# Express Edition command line arguments from the IDE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have a small program, which just test the Command line in Visual C# Express Edition.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
```

namespace ConsoleApplication_CommandLine
{

```
public class CommandLine2
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number of command line parameters = {0}",
           args.Length);
        foreach (string s in args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

}

I want to give the input as like java, i.e. java "AppName"

How can that be done in Visual studio.. In small, I wish to give command line arguments in Visual C# Express Edition from the IDE.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Project Properties, Debug tab. It has a multiline textbox for adding parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Have no the *Express* edition, but the place is the same. 
Have a look [Specify Command Line Arguments in Visual Studio 2010](http://csharp.2000things.com/2010/06/30/specify-command-line-arguments-in-visual-studio-2010/)

[image: Project properties screen]

Comment: @HenkHolterman: oh god ! My screen shot! No I'm just writing a dental software :) Was in the middle of long calculation so responding to answer too.. :) Will change it. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

for testing purposes you can even hardcode this array